# Где хранятся сейвы игр на Android? (кроме Android/data/)

Tags: android

Решил сегодня сделать продвижение в игре легче, для этого надо чуть увеличить некоторую прокачку. Игра кидает данные на сервер когда есть интернет, когда его нету - берет сохранения с устройства.

Первым делом пошел искать в `/data/user/0/имя пакета/shared_prefs`, но там нет ничего нужного.

Дальше пошел проверил `Android/obb/имя пакета` - пустая папка, а от в `Android/data/имя пакета/files/` нашел сохранения игры. Их там 4, видимо новые добавляются, старые удаляются.

Если пробую что-то менять в последнем сохранении, то игра подгружается с предыдущих сейвов. Если предыдущие сейвы удаляю - то вобще непонятно откуда но тоже подгружается (интернет все время выключен).

Для теста вообще удалил папку `Android/data/имя пакета`, и при заходе в игру начинается все сначала, но через секунды две пишет Loading и игра откуда-то загружается. Не могу понять откуда. Где хранится еще сохранение?

Comment: Внутренняя память приложения это `/data/data/<package>`, у вас будет доступ до этой директории, если телефон рутованный. Либо если приложение было собрано в дебаг-режиме.

Comment: Если нет рутованного устройства, то можно воспрозоваться эмулятором.

Comment: Сейвы могут храниться где угодно и как угодно - всё зависит от фантазии разработчика. Для этого может быть использован любой тип файла в любом расположении, доступном приложению. Если приложение не было остановлено (убито) на момент удаления файлов, то данные могут оставаться в памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, сейвы могут храниться во внутренней памяти приложения. В Андроиде это `/data/data/<package>`, где <package> — имя пакета приложения.

Способы, как попасть в эту дриректорию (используя [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)):

1. Если телефон рутованный, то делаем `adb root`, далее `adb shell`, далее `cd /data/data/<package>`. Если нет рутованного девайса, можно воспользоваться эмулятором, который входит в поставку [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)
2. Если телефон не рутованный, а приложение собрано в дебаг-режиме, то делаем `adb shell`, далее `run-as <package>`, после чего мы сразу оказываемся в `/data/data/<package>`
3. Если телефон не рутованный, и приложение не является debuggable, то можно попробовать сделать бэкап внутреннего хранилища с помощью команды `adb backup -noapk <package>` (этот способ сработает только в случае, если при сборке приложения был включен флаг allowBackup)

Comment: У меня телефон рутованный, в папке `/data/data/<package>` файлов с сейвами нет.